# Locking configuration file in APPDATA directory while C# Windows application is running

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, file-io

I have an application with a manifest file that needs a bunch of configuration files (XML).
Those files sit in %PROGRAMDATA%\MyApp\Config.

What I would like to do is lock the files while the app is running, so only the app (several objects in it need to write to the file) can **write to and read from** the file.

I have a base class that loads the Xml using a stream reader like so:

```
document = new XmlDocument();
reader = new StreamReader( new FileStream( fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite ) );
document.Load( fileName );
```

This lockes the file alright. But obviously that is not enough since inheriting classes now can't call `document.Save()` since it will not save the file. It is locked.

Do I need an StreamWriter to be able to save the file now?
How does that work?

Thank you!!

Comment: Use the *using* statement.

Comment: Hans, that reader will be disposed since the class is IDisposable. Is that not enough, or is that too late?